# Entire DB find replace in all procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, replace

I have inherited a db that contains approx 150 stored procs that have references to db objects on that same server. It worked fine, until the db was moved to another server, now the procedures cannot find those objects.

for example: what is commonplace is simply [database].[dbo].[object], when what should have occurred is [server].[database].[dbo].[object], for these references not be break.

I am presently using

`select [definition] 
    into #test
    from sys.sql_modules 
    where definition like '%(db name)%'`

To locate the procs with references to the db, and possibly doing a `REPLACE` on each db match.

But is there simpler way?

Comment: Why dont you move the procedures where the database was moved?

Comment: Maybe you can create a list of views with the same name as the tables and in the view add the full name with the server address. I dont know how this will perform but it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickest/Easiest way to use Search/Replace through all stored procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269172/quickest-easiest-way-to-use-search-replace-through-all-stored-procedures)

Comment: @TabAlleman This question is different from Quickest/Easiest way to use Search/Replace through all stored procedures because this question is looking for a programmatic way to accomplish, not simply bulk find an replace, i may have upwards of 15 different db references, that often share the same object names, but different servers (bad design overall)

Comment: This is not the same question, he wants to change the procedures the question mentioned here updates the content of the tables.

Comment: If you create a script of the database with the store procedures you can cut the procedures section and make a find replace. And then use the script to recreate or to update the procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider use `SYNONYM`

```
USE [database];
GO
CREATE SYNONYM [object] FOR [server].[database].[dbo].[object];
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for this information, I didn't created the question but this information is useful, i learned something