# SQL Server: Search and Replace a string in all database objects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that finds the given text in procedures/functions/triggers from selected DB (Not jobs and table data):

```
Declare @SearchStr varchar(256) = 'MyStringToSearchFor'

SELECT 
       OBJECT_NAME(object_id), 
       OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) as SchemaName, 
       definition
FROM  
       sys.sql_modules
WHERE 
       definition LIKE '%'+@SearchStr+'%'
```

**Is there any way to automatically replace the string found by some other string?**

Comment: If you mean to update `sys.sql_modules`, no, that is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickest/Easiest way to use Search/Replace through all stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269172/quickest-easiest-way-to-use-search-replace-through-all-stored-procedures)